# Convert multiple objects to json in ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In my ajax post I want to convert 2 objects to JSON, is that possible?

I've tried `data: ko.toJSON(obj1, obj2)` without success. 
It works if I add both objects into an Array and them pass to `toJSON()`, but that's not what I'm after.

The reason is that I want to take 2 input parameters in my controller like:

```
 public ActionResult CopyStoredProcedures(CopyStoredProceduresModel model, CopyStoredProceduresModel model2) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new object with two properties, and convert it to `JSON`:

```
var data = {
    model: obj1,
    model2: obj2
}
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

I guess that obj1 and obj2 are not viewModels. If they are knockout viewModels, then they should be converted to js before converting to `JSON`:

```
var data = {
    model: ko.toJS(obj1),
    model2: ko.toJS(obj2)
}
```